# Turning off custom script SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, theme

I was looking for a way to prevent users from changing the design in SharePoint Online. The documentation pointed me to http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/turn-scripting-capabilities-on-and-off-HA104182969.aspx. In my tenant (E3) I cannot find this option. Anyone know what the status is of that functionality?

I think revoking the permissions AddAndCustomizePages and ApplyThemeAndBorder should do the trick. Is there any other way to prevent site owners from applying another theme?